# Opposite to Hold Event in Windows Phone 8 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am creating simple app that will play sound when an image is holded (tap and hold). Therefore I am using Hold Event.
But i need to stop playing sounds when somebody releases their finger from image.
There is no "Release" or "Unhold" Event, so how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have asked a similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967407/windows-phone-8-manipulate-scrollviewer-through-image-hold-event), but I haven't gotten any reply. Our problems are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop playing sounds upon [ManipulationCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationcompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event called. Note that, that event will get invoked after any gesture manipulation including [Tap, Double Tap, Hold, and other gesture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426933%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Take that into account. For example, by having a flag to indicate whether sound already playing or not :

```
private void MyImage_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(isSoundPlaying) stopSound();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `MouseLeftButtonUp`. The name might be confusing (in case of touch devices). See more at: [Quickstart: Touch input for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207076%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). It lists MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseLeftButtonUp, MouseLeave, MouseMove, MouseEnter as the mouse events used by Windows Phone to react to touch.

Note that there will be a problem when user Holds in the image area but then releases the hold *outside* the image area - `MouseLeftButtonUp will not be raised. So you also need to handle`MouseLeave` and make sure the sound has already been stopped.